# Google autocomplete text is white

Tags: google-maps

I have google maps autocomplete working perfectly, but the text returned is all white. I know it's there because when I hover over it, I see the rest of the suggestion.

[image]

How do I change this?

**EDIT:**

This is what my CSS looks like for the autocomplete:

```
.pac-container {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3vh;
    height: 45vh;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: none;
}

.pac-item {
    height: 5vh;
    color: #A0A09F;
}

.pac-matched {
    color: #605E5E;
}

.pac-item-query {
    color: #605E5E;
}
```

How would I get the text to look like so:

[image]

Comment: Why the downvote? To my knowledge, there isn't anything in the documentation that states where the text gets its color from?

Comment: It is probably a CSS issue.  What does your CSS look like?

Comment: @geocodezip I assumed there was an issue with that, but the documentation doesn't really specify where that text get's it's color from and how to change it. I added my CSS

Comment: try `.pac-item span {
    color: #605E5E !important;
}`

Comment: @Dr.Molle That worked! How would I keep the .pac-matched and .pac-item-query a different color? For example, I'm trying to get the text to display like it does when you search on google maps. I added another image to show you what I mean.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I got it to work like the picture above by adding !important to the two classes I mentioned. Feel free to answer the question and I'll mark yours as correct!